# error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and 'void')|

Tags: c++, c++11

This is my code. I have gone through it multiple times, making many changes still same error.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void checkAge(int age){
    if(age >= 18){
        cout<< "As your age is above 18, you are eligible to vote. \n";
    }
    else{
        cout<< "As your age is below 18, you aren't eligible to vote. \n";
    }
}
int main()
{
    int age;
        cout << "Enter your age. \n";
       cin >> age;
       cout << checkAge(age);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `checkAge` does not return any value. Still, it outputs string on its own using `cout`. So `checkAge(age);` without `cout <<` is enough.

Comment: Without looking inside `checkAge` and looking only at its signature, can you tell what kind of data `cout << checkAge(age)` is supposed to print?

Answer (score 1):

Your function `checkAge` does not return anything. So just remove the `cout` from

```
cout << checkAge(age);
```

That is replace the above statement to just:

```
checkAge(age);
```

**Solution 2**

Another solution would be to return an `int` from the `checkAge`. For example you could change you function definition to:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void checkAge(int age){
    if(age >= 18){
        cout<< "As your age is above 18, you are eligible to vote. \n";
    }
    else{
        cout<< "As your age is below 18, you aren't eligible to vote. \n";
    }
    return age;//added return so that cout << checkAge(age) would work
}
int main()
{
    int age;
        cout << "Enter your age. \n";
       cin >> age;
       cout << checkAge(age);


    return 0;
}
```